# find key exist in json onject

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
"questions": [{
        "_id": "5b2bc4f6f1dacd2b0ca65bca",
        "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:06.237Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:06.237Z",
        "title": "What is Full form of RC",
        "answer": "opt4",
        "testId": "5b2bbccd8b30aa2a64327645",
        "__v": 0,
        "opt4": "Registeraction Certificate",
        "opt3": "Requirement Certificate",
        "opt2": "Registeration Common",
        "opt1": "Registeration Counter",
        "solution": "RC means Registeraction Certificate"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b2bc4faf1dacd2b0ca65bcd",
        "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:10.566Z",
        "createdAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:10.566Z",
        "title": "What is Full form of RC",
        "answer": "opt4",
        "testId": "5b2bbccd8b30aa2a64327645",
        "__v": 0,
        "opt4": "Registeraction Certificate",
        "opt3": "Requirement Certificate",
        "opt2": "Registeration Common",
        "opt1": "Registeration Counter",
        "solution": "RC means Registeraction Certificate"
    }
]
```

Above are my data which using in **ques.map()**

```
var ans = {
    "5b2bc4f6f1dacd2b0ca65bca": "opt4",
    "5b2bc4faf1dacd2b0ca65bcd": "opt2",
    "5b2bc4fcf1dacd2b0ca65bcf": "opt2",
    "5b2bc4fff1dacd2b0ca65bd1": "opt4",
    "5b2bc501f1dacd2b0ca65bd3": "opt2",
    "5b2bc504f1dacd2b0ca65bd6": "opt2",
    "5b2bc5facdf99b18a0b9722b": "opt2",
    "5b2bc6295865b528dceeb6b7": "opt2",
    "5b2bc6ba7f32b21f7c68e57f": "opt2",
    "5b2bc6bc7f32b21f7c68e580": "opt2"
}
```

I need to find if key exists in above json object, but I'm not able to get it.
Its always returns false.

```
console.log(ans);
ques.map(function(item) {
    var thisIs = ans.hasOwnProperty(item._id)
    console.log(thisIs);
})
```

It always return **false**

Comment: Do you want questions for which _id is exist in ans?

Answer (score 0):

try this updated code

without `jquery (down voter)`

use

```
Object.keys(ques).map(function(key, index) {
  Object.keys(ques[key]).map(function(key1, index1) {
    var thisis = ans.hasOwnProperty(ques[key][key1]['_id']);
    console.log(thisis);
  });
 });
```

```js
var ques = {
  "questions": [{
      "_id": "5b2bc4f6f1dacd2b0ca65bca",
      "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:06.237Z",
      "createdAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:06.237Z",
      "title": "What is Full form of RC",
      "answer": "opt4",
      "testId": "5b2bbccd8b30aa2a64327645",
      "__v": 0,
      "opt4": "Registeraction Certificate",
      "opt3": "Requirement Certificate",
      "opt2": "Registeration Common",
      "opt1": "Registeration Counter",
      "solution": "RC means Registeraction Certificate"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b2bc4faf1dacd2b0ca65bcd",
      "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:10.566Z",
      "createdAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:10.566Z",
      "title": "What is Full form of RC",
      "answer": "opt4",
      "testId": "5b2bbccd8b30aa2a64327645",
      "__v": 0,
      "opt4": "Registeraction Certificate",
      "opt3": "Requirement Certificate",
      "opt2": "Registeration Common",
      "opt1": "Registeration Counter",
      "solution": "RC means Registeraction Certificate"
    }
  ]
}


var ans = {
  "5b2bc4f6f1dacd2b0ca65bca": "opt4",
  "5b2bc4faf1dacd2b0ca65bcd": "opt2",
  "5b2bc4fcf1dacd2b0ca65bcf": "opt2",
  "5b2bc4fff1dacd2b0ca65bd1": "opt4",
  "5b2bc501f1dacd2b0ca65bd3": "opt2",
  "5b2bc504f1dacd2b0ca65bd6": "opt2",
  "5b2bc5facdf99b18a0b9722b": "opt2",
  "5b2bc6295865b528dceeb6b7": "opt2",
  "5b2bc6ba7f32b21f7c68e57f": "opt2",
  "5b2bc6bc7f32b21f7c68e580": "opt2"
}


//console.log(ques);
Object.keys(ques).map(function(key, index) {
  Object.keys(ques[key]).map(function(key1, index1) {
    var thisis = ans.hasOwnProperty(ques[key][key1]['_id']);
    console.log(thisis);
  });

});
```

Comment: surely there's a solution that doesn't require jQuery

Comment: but `ques.map` not a function for loop

Comment: what about `for` `forEach` `while`?

Comment: hello MR @Itamar plsss check my code without `jquery`

Comment: map is not needed, nor its a loop function

Comment: so why you not give a answer instead of give a lecture @i

Comment: si first give answer after that comment on others answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use match the key in the object using for loop.

```
ques.forEach((item)=>{
  for (var key in ans) {
    if (key == item._id){
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You’re not returning anything from map() - use forEach() instead. Also your for loop can be replaced by another forEach() so you keep the code concise.

Comment: `map` is not a looping function`

Comment: Thanks, updated! I initially focused on matching the key. I didn't noticed that.

Comment: @Prachi nope. its returning false

Comment: It doesn't even enter the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

> Using @dr-strange answer as a basis for this answer
>   Without Using `map` or anything related.

This is the basic code

```
Object.keys(ques).forEach(function(key) { //loop over upper level keys
  Object.keys(ques[key]).forEach(function(innerKey) { //loop second level keys
    var thisIs = ans.hasOwnProperty(ques[key][innerKey]['_id']); //compare keys
    console.log(thisIs);
    return; // break loop
  });
```

});

```js
var ques = {
  "questions": [{
      "_id": "5b2bc4f6f1dacd2b0ca65bca",
      "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:06.237Z",
      "createdAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:06.237Z",
      "title": "What is Full form of RC",
      "answer": "opt4",
      "testId": "5b2bbccd8b30aa2a64327645",
      "__v": 0,
      "opt4": "Registeraction Certificate",
      "opt3": "Requirement Certificate",
      "opt2": "Registeration Common",
      "opt1": "Registeration Counter",
      "solution": "RC means Registeraction Certificate"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b2bc4faf1dacd2b0ca65bcd",
      "updatedAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:10.566Z",
      "createdAt": "2018-06-21T15:32:10.566Z",
      "title": "What is Full form of RC",
      "answer": "opt4",
      "testId": "5b2bbccd8b30aa2a64327645",
      "__v": 0,
      "opt4": "Registeraction Certificate",
      "opt3": "Requirement Certificate",
      "opt2": "Registeration Common",
      "opt1": "Registeration Counter",
      "solution": "RC means Registeraction Certificate"
    }
  ]
}


var ans = {
  "5b2bc4f6f1dacd2b0ca65bca": "opt4",
  "5b2bc4faf1dacd2b0ca65bcd": "opt2",
  "5b2bc4fcf1dacd2b0ca65bcf": "opt2",
  "5b2bc4fff1dacd2b0ca65bd1": "opt4",
  "5b2bc501f1dacd2b0ca65bd3": "opt2",
  "5b2bc504f1dacd2b0ca65bd6": "opt2",
  "5b2bc5facdf99b18a0b9722b": "opt2",
  "5b2bc6295865b528dceeb6b7": "opt2",
  "5b2bc6ba7f32b21f7c68e57f": "opt2",
  "5b2bc6bc7f32b21f7c68e580": "opt2"
}



Object.keys(ques).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.keys(ques[key]).forEach(function(innerKey) {
    var thisIs = ans.hasOwnProperty(ques[key][innerKey]['_id']);
    console.log(thisIs);
    return;
  });
   });
```